# Boost.Hana test if lambda is callable with particular argument

Tags: c++, sfinae, compile-time, boost-hana

I want to test if a `callable` lambda can be called with particular arguments by using Boost.Hana. The compiler complains that `callable` expects 0 arguments but 1 were provided. Isn't the `if_` a compile time if that does compile depending on the condition `is_callable`?

Maybe someone has an idea of how to get the code to work.

```cpp
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

int main(){

  namespace bh = boost::hana;

  auto is_callable = bh::is_valid([](auto&& callable, auto&& args) -> decltype(bh::unpack(args, callable)){});        

  auto callable = [](){};
  auto arg = 1;
  auto args = bh::make_tuple(arg);

  bh::if_(is_callable(callable, args),
                   [arg](auto callable){ callable(arg);},
                   [](auto callable){})(callable);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The main issue here is that `unpack` is not SFINAE friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jason Rice mentioned in the comments, the reason this fails is that [`hana::unpack`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-Foldable.html#ga7b0c23944364ce61136e10b978ae2170) is not SFINAE friendly. The easiest way to work around this is to call the callable ourselves for `hana::is_valid`, using `hana::unpack` to unpack the arguments into the result of `hana::is_valid`:

```
auto const is_callable = [](auto&& callable, auto&& args) {
    return bh::unpack(args,
        bh::is_valid([&callable](auto&&... args)
            -> decltype(callable(args...))
        {})
    );
};
```

[Live demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Xd2r4R)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think your live demo needs a little modification, since the `not_callable` is not used as parameter for the `if_`. Furthermore, I modified your code a little bit, such that the callable takes an auto argument and tries to access a member which is not available. Shouldn't the `is_valid` call also catch this? See here the code: https://godbolt.org/z/uY6fpp

Comment: @erikzenker Nice catch on that typo; it happens to not affect the result because we're not calling the parameter anyway. For your modifications to take an `auto` parameter, the `is_valid` call has no way of catching that. The callable needs to SFINAE away, and the body of a lambda is not an SFINAE context. You'd have to put it in an SFINAE context for it to work. https://godbolt.org/z/n2Yzuo